# How to make an animation visible only within certain areas of an SVG?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I hope you can help me out. I am trying to add a "shine" animation to my SVG, but I only want the animation to be visible in certain parts of my SVG, and I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

I have posted what I have so far below.

I want the white "shine" animation to only be visible within the blue arrow polygons, and not visible in the orange background.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

```css
.shine {
  background: orange -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#222), to(#222), color-stop(0.5, #fff)) 0 0 no-repeat;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(-40deg, transparent 0%, transparent 40%, #fff 50%, transparent 60%, transparent 100%);
  -webkit-background-size: 200%;
  -webkit-animation-name: shine;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 3s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes shine {
  0% {
    background-position: 150%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: -50%
  }
}
```

```html
<svg class='shine'>
    <polygon fill="blue" class='arrow-top' points='37.6,27.9 1.8,1.3 3.3,0 37.6,25.3 71.9,0 73.7,1.3'></polygon>
    <polygon fill="blue" class='arrow-middle' points='37.6,45.8 0.8,18.7 4.4,16.4 37.6,41.2 71.2,16.4 74.5,18.7'></polygon>
    <polygon fill="blue" class='arrow-bottom' points='37.6,64 0,36.1 5.1,32.8 37.6,56.8 70.4,32.8 75.5,36.1'></polygon>
</svg>
```

Comment: You might have to change how you’ve set the styles. The main point is you don’t want to put the animation on `.shine` you want it in the arrow classes. That said, you will likely need to change it from background. If there isn’t an answer in a bit, I’ll sort something out for you. —— you’ll probably want to use a mask and translate another element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where I use [`<animate>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/animate) on a [`<linearGradient>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/linearGradient). The gradient is used on a mask that masks off the three polygons.

```html
<svg width="200" viewBox="0 0 75.5 65" class="shine" fill="url(#g1)">
  <defs>
    <linearGradient id="g1" x1="-100" x2="-50" gradientTransform="rotate(40)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#fff" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#222" />
      <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#fff" />
      <animate
      attributeName="x1"
      values="-100;100"
      dur="3s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
      <animate
      attributeName="x2"
      values="-50;250"
      dur="3s"
      repeatCount="indefinite" />
    </linearGradient>
    <mask id="m1">
      <rect transform="translate(0 0)" width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#g1)"/>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  <g mask="url(#m1)">
    <polygon fill="blue" class='arrow-top' points='37.6,27.9 1.8,1.3 3.3,0 37.6,25.3 71.9,0 73.7,1.3'></polygon>
    <polygon fill="blue" class='arrow-middle' points='37.6,45.8 0.8,18.7 4.4,16.4 37.6,41.2 71.2,16.4 74.5,18.7'></polygon>
    <polygon fill="blue" class='arrow-bottom' points='37.6,64 0,36.1 5.1,32.8 37.6,56.8 70.4,32.8 75.5,36.1'></polygon>
  </g>
</svg>
```